# Do I need to declare a delay timer variable as volatile even if I access it from another module

Tags: c++, c, compiler, optimization

This is a question more about using volatile to prevent optimization than about caching write/read of a variable. Particularly timer delay variables since I don't want to declare everything volatile and waste optimization in doing so.

First off, I know the following snippet will not work if optimization is turned on unless I declare i volatile:

```
int i;
for(i=0; i<LARGE_NUM; i++); //Delay for a bit
```

What if the loop invoke a function call and wait on that instead, will the compiler look across source files and optimize the call out? I'm asking this because some compilers offer multi-file compilation.

```
//A.c
#include "B.h"    //B.h has declaration for dec(int)

...
int i;
for(i=LARGE_NUM; i>0; i=dec(i));
...

//B.c

int dec(int a){
  return a-1;
}
```

What about something a bit more complex and involves hardware interrupt?

```
//A.c
#include "B.h"

...
timer_start(LARGE_NUM);
while(timer_busy());
...

void hardware_timer_isr(void){    //Hardware timer interrupt
    timer_tick();
}

//B.c

static int time=0;

void timer_start(int t){
    time = t;
}

int timer_busy(void){
    return time>0;
}

void timer_tick(void){
    if(time > 0)
        time--;
}
```

Will I need to declare the variables as volatile in any of the cases? Or are there anything in particular that I should also look out for?

Comment: For non-tiny delays (e.g. more than microsecond on a GHz desktop or tablet processor), it is much better to avoid busy loops and rely on e.g. your operating system or your scheduler (for embedded systems)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler operates under the [as-if rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) that allows any and all code transformations that don't change the observable behavior of the program.

[C++14: 1.5/8]

> The least requirements on a conforming implementation are:
>
> - Access to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine.
> - At program termination, all data written into files shall be identical to one of the possible results that execution of the program according to the abstract semantics would have produced.
> - The input and output dynamics of interactive devices shall take place in such a fashion that prompting output is actually delivered before a program waits for input. What constitutes an interactive device is implementation-defined.
>
> These collectively are referred to as the observable behavior of the program.

[C11 5.1.2.3.6 Program execution] has a similar wording:

> The least requirements on a conforming implementation are:
>
> - Accesses to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine.
> - At program termination, all data written into files shall be identical to the result that execution of the program according to the abstract semantics would have produced.
> - The input and output dynamics of interactive devices shall take place as specified in 7.21.3. The intent of these requirements is that unbuffered or line-buffered output appear as soon as possible, to ensure that prompting messages actually appear prior to a program waiting for input.
>
> This is the observable behavior of the program.

A delay is not considered an observable behavior and the first example can be "optimized" to an empty program.

Note that, to allow compiler transformations such as removal of empty loops (even when termination cannot be proven), C++14 standards says:

[C++14: 1.10/24]

> The implementation may assume that any thread will eventually do one of the following:
>
> - terminate,
> - make a call to a library I/O function,
> - access or modify a volatile object, or
> - perform a synchronization operation or an atomic operation.
>
> [ Note: This is intended to allow compiler transformations such as removal of empty loops, even when termination cannot be proven. —end note ]

(see also [Does C/C++ offer any guarantee on minimal execution time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36814199/3235496))

---

The second example is harder for the compiler because it is usually unable to analyze the code of an external library to determine whether it does / doesn't perform I/O or volatile access. However statically-linked third-party library code may be subject to [link-time optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocedural_optimization) so 
a multi-file organization isn't an insurmountable barrier.

---

The third example doesn't introduce anything new:

1. the interrupt vector entry is initialized at program startup
2. that involves taking address of the handler function and it's sufficient to protect `hardware_timer_isr` from being optimized out
3. but the `time` variable isn't manually designated as a variable that can be changed by interrupt handlers so the instructions:

   ```
    timer_start(LARGE_NUM);
    while(timer_busy());
   ```

   haven't an observable behavior and can be optimized out (see [Why does the compiler not optimize away interrupt code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25576812/3235496) for further details).

---

If you need a delay you can use [`std::sleep_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) or [`std::sleep_until`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until).

---

**FURTHER NOTES**

> What if I deliberately put a `while(1);` or a similarly obfuscated infinite loop to intentionally halt the program? According to C++14 1.10/24 above, even though the termination can not be proven, the loop itself does not change the observable behavior of the program and thus can be legally removed, right?

The reason of the note (*"this is intended to allow compiler transformations such as removal of empty loops, even when termination cannot be proven"*) is 
there's no way to [detect infinite loops universally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) and the inability to prove termination hampers compilers which could otherwise make useful transformations (there is a good example in [N1528: Why undefined behavior for infinite loops?](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1528.htm)).

For the C++ language the situation is described in:

- [Optimizing away a “while(1);” in C++0x](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3592557/3235496) by Hans Boehm
- [Compilers and Termination Revisited](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/161) by John Regehr

For the C language [C11 provides an exception for controlling expressions that are constant expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28681034/3235496).

Comment: So, if the modules are dynamically linked, the second and third example would work as intended since the compiler can not make any assumption on the flow of the program?

Also, shouldn't the third example boils down to an infinite loop, since `time>0` should never be false if `time` is non volatile?

Comment: Which brings a new question up: What if I deliberately put a `while(1);` or a similarly obfuscated infinite loop to intentionally halt the program? According to C++14 1.10/24 above, even though the termination can not be proven, the loop itself does not change the observable behavior of the program and thus can be legally removed, right?

Comment: @Pyxzure I've added further notes.